# how i get a coordinate of each rectangle?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, html5-canvas, geometry

[image]
i have tried this,

```
  public drawNumbers(ctx, x1, y1, length, count) {
      let angle = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++ ) {
        angle += 2 * Math.PI / (count );
      const x2 = x1 + length * Math.cos(angle),
        y2 = y1 + length * Math.sin(angle);
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.fillRect(x2, y2, 10, 20);
       ctx.stroke();

    }
  }

    this.canvas.drawNumbers(ctx, this.midX, this.midY, 160, 60);
```

output:

[image]

expected result:

i want to calculate a four coordinate(rectangle) of rotated axis.

How do i detect click event on each rectangle?

[image]

Comment: The simplest way to shift angles- initialization `let angle =  - Math.Pi / 2`

Comment: Can you clarify what is wanted? You seem to ask different things in the title and question body.

Comment: @Salixalba i have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using setTransform

Salix alba answer is a solution though a few too many steps.

It can be done in a single transform using `setTransform` and applying the translate and rotations in one step. Also the second translation is where you draw the box relative to its origin. When using transforms always draw objects around the center of rotation.

```
 ctx.strokeRect(-10,-10,20,20); // rotation is always around 0,0
```

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const centerX = 250;
const centerY = 250;
const radius = 200;
const boxWidth = 10;
const bobLength = 20;

// draw boxs around circle center at cx,cy and radius rad
// box width bw, and box height bh
// spacing optional is the distance between boxes
function drawCircleOfBoxes(cx,cy,rad,bw,bh,spacing = 5){
  var steps = ((rad - bw /2) * Math.PI * 2) / (bw + spacing) | 0; // get number boxes that will fit circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i = 0; i < steps; i ++){
      const ang = (i / steps) * Math.PI * 2;
      var xAxisX = Math.cos(ang);  // get the direction of he xAxis
      var xAxisY = Math.sin(ang);
      // set the transform to circle center x Axis out towards box
      // y axis at 90 deg to x axis
      ctx.setTransform(xAxisX, xAxisY, -xAxisY, xAxisX, cx, cy);
      // draw box offset from the center so its center is distance radius
      ctx.rect(rad - bh / 2, -bw / 2, bh, bw);
  }
  ctx.fill(); 
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
}

ctx.fillStyle = "#FCD";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
drawCircleOfBoxes(centerX, centerY, radius, boxWidth, bobLength);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

### Manually apply the transform to a point

If you wish to transform the box in code you can use the transform applied in the above and apply it directly to a set of points. You can not apply it to the `ctx.rect` function that needs the API transform.

To transform a point `px`,`py` you need the the direction of the rotated x axis

```
const xAx = Math.cos(dirOfXAxis);
const xAy = Math.sin(dirOfXAxis);
```

You can then move the point `px` distance along the xAxis and then turn 90 deg and move `py` distance along the y axis

```
var x = px * xAx;  // move px dist along x axis
var y = px * xAy;

x += py * -xAy;  // move px dist along y axis
y += py * xAx;
```

Then just add the translation

```
x += translateX;
y += translateY;
```

Or done in one go

```
var x = px * xAx - py * xAy + translateX;  // move px dist along x axis
var y = px * xAy + py * xAx + translateY;
```

The snippet shows it in action

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const centerX = 250;
const centerY = 250;
const radius = 200;
const boxWidth = 10;
const boxLength = 20;


// draw boxs around circle center at cx,cy and radius rad
// box width bw, and box height bh
// spacing optional is the distance between boxes
function drawCircleOfBoxes(cx,cy,rad,bw,bh,spacing = 5){
  var points = [  // setout points of box with coord (0,0) as center
    {x : bh / 2, y :  -bw / 2},
    {x : bh / 2 + bh, y :  -bw / 2},
    {x : bh / 2 + bh, y :  -bw / 2 + bw},
    {x : bh / 2, y :  -bw / 2 + bw},
  ];
  var steps = (((rad - bw /2) * Math.PI * 2) / (bw + spacing) )+ 4| 0; // get number boxes that will fit circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i = 0; i < steps; i ++){
      const ang = (i / steps) * Math.PI * 2;
      const xAx = Math.cos(ang);  // get the direction of he xAxis
      const xAy = Math.sin(ang);
      var first = true
      for(const p of points){ // for each point
          // Apply the transform to the point after moving it
          // to the circle (the p.x + rad)
          const x = (p.x + rad) * xAx - p.y * xAy + cx;
          const y = (p.x + rad) * xAy + p.y * xAx + cy;
          if(first){
             ctx.moveTo(x,y);
             first = false;
          }else{
             ctx.lineTo(x,y);
          }
      }
      ctx.closePath();
  }

  ctx.fill(); 
  ctx.stroke();

}


ctx.fillStyle = "#CFD";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";

for(var i = boxLength + 5; i < radius; i += boxLength + 5){
    drawCircleOfBoxes(centerX, centerY, i , boxWidth, boxLength);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: How do i detect click event on each rectangle?. i am getting opposite Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: x=161, y = -5.5  while clicking on mouse, i am getting  x=-161, y=-5.5.

Comment: @DharanG Get the vector from circle center to mouse `vx = mx - cx; vy =my - cy;` where m is mouse, c is circle center. Then get the bearing `b = Math.atan(vy, vx)`  y is first argument, normalize bearing `b = (b + Math.PI * 2) % (Math.PI * 2). Using the `steps` variable (top of `drawCircleOfBoxes` function) calculate the angular width `aw` of box. `aw = Math.PI / steps` Find distance from center to mouse `dist = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy)` use `boxLength` and `radius` to see if mouse is correct dist `overRing = dist >= radius - boxLength /2 && dist < radius + boxLength / 2`...   continues

Comment: @DharanG add angular width to bearing  `b += aw` (aw is actually half angular width. Divide bearing by angular width and floor to get box index `boxIndex = (b / (aw * 2)) | 0;`  That will give the which box. But it is not perfect. If you want perfect you need to create an inverse transform for each box and apply that to the mouse coordinates. Then just use those coords to check if the mouse is inside the box.

Comment: @DharanG sorry that is not the question asked. You will have to create another question.

Comment: @DharanG Sorry I don't do chat, I only answer questions.

Comment: i have updated the question. can you please share any resource for this?. it is difficult to go through two part of comment. that's why i have updated.

Answer (score 0):

To get rotated rectangles you need to use the [transform()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform) method of the graphics context.

Imagine a set of axis at the top left of the drawing area. Any drawing will be done relative to these axis which we can move with transform.

To translate by xshift, yshift

```
ctx.transform(1,0,0,1, xshift,  yshift);
ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```

To rotate by angle ang in radians

```
ctx.transform(Math.cos(ang),Math.sin(ang),
              -Math.sin(ang),Math.cos(ang),  0,0);
```

We can combine things with three transformations. The first moves the origin to the center of the circle. Then rotate the axes about this point,
then shift the axes to where you want the shape to appear. Finally, draw the shape.

```
for(deg = 0; deg < 360; deg+=20) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transformation
    ang = deg * Math.PI/180;
    ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,100,100); // shift origin
    ctx.transform(Math.cos(ang),Math.sin(ang),
                 -Math.sin(ang),Math.cos(ang),  0,0);
    ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,50,0);
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,10);
}
```

You can achieve the same this using the `translate` and `rotate`

```
for(deg = 0; deg < 360; deg+=20) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transformation
    ang = deg * Math.PI/180;
    ctx.translate(100,100); // shift origin
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(50,0);
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,10);
}
```